# LibGDX move shaperender smooth

Tags: java, graphics, libgdx, render, smoothing

I am using Shaperender to render Circle and in the update function at everyloop I update che coordinates that rappresent my objects (the circles).

I am not using textures, only shaperender and I can't achieve a smooth movement, what am I doing wrong? (I am on Android)

As you can see there is some kind of trail/lag when the blue circle is moving.
**Please watch the video instead of the gif: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsTac.jpg**

[image]

this is the code:

```
public void update(float dt){
            x = centerX + (float)Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle)) * trajectory;
            y = centerY + (float)Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle)) * trajectory;
    }


public void render(SpriteBatch sb) {
            // --- sr is a new ShapeRenderer declared in the constructor as sr = new ShapeRenderer()

            sr.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
            sr.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            sr.circle(x,y, radius , 100);

            sr.end();
            }
```

Comment: TBH, I don't see much lag but maybe I'm just tired. But I guess it's got something to do with FPS changes. Regarding the angle variable which you probably update each render - do you multiply the "speed" (the value you add to the current angle at each render) of the angle rotation with the delta time value? If not, you should. It'll make it frame-rate-independent